# How can I determine whether a property is a Generic Type in DNX Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, dnx

Previously I could use this to get the generic types on a class;

```
typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Any(p => p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
```

However, in DNX Core 5.0, `IsGenericType` is not supported.  What can I use now?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just looked through some source here that confirms there is still a  IsGenericType property in the framework.

https://github.com/aspnet/Common/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Framework.ClosedGenericMatcher.Sources/ClosedGenericMatcher.cs#L44

Does the following work?

```
typeof(MyClass).GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.Any(p => p.PropertyType.GetTypeInfo().IsGenericType)
```

Comment: Hey cheers, just added `GetTypeInfo()` to `PropertyType` as per your example and it compiles.

Comment: No problem! The TypeInfo class and method GetTypeInfo() was added in .NET 4.5: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/08/28/evolving-the-reflection-api.aspx